# Manipulate String using powershell and regex

Tags: regex, powershell, replace

I have an html file which has a part like this:

```
                <li>
                    <a href="../index.html" name="" title="title1">title1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="level1/level1.html" name="" title="title2">title2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="levl1/level2/level2.html" name="" title="title3">title3</a>
                </li>
```

I want them to look like this:

```
                <li>
                    <a href="../" name="" title="title1">title1</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="level1/" name="" title="title2">title2</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="level1/level2/" name="" title="title3">title3</a>
                </li>
```

I wrote a script in powershell to manipulate these href links which look like this:

```
(Get-Content $i) -replace '/*.html', '/' | Set-Content $i
```

But somehow the output is not coming as expected. Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Comment: How is the output coming? Is it a secret?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use something like this:

```
(Get-Content in.html) -replace '\/[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+\.html', '/' | Set-Content out.html
```

Comment: because I used `\w` which matches any word character, it's equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9]`, now I used a different match, so if you need any other strange char (but `/`) just add it to the `[]` expression

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer to get a wider context to look for from the beginnig of the tag since the regex may find some other unexpected patterns

```
( Get-Content $i ) -ireplace '(<a\s+href="[^"]*/).*?(?=")','$1' | Set-Content $i
```

Hope that there is a typo in the 8th line otherwise you can also make 'level1/' from 'levl1/' throughout the file

```
( Get-Content $i ) -ireplace '(<a\s+href="[^"]*/).*?(?=")','$1' -ireplace 'levl1/','level1/' | Set-Content $i
```

Comment: Yeah its a typo. It should be level1. Thank you anyway!